# Reassign a value to an array element

Tags: symbolic, assignment

I have a very complex code in which I assign a value to an element of an array and then I reassign to it another one. A minimal example:

```
Clear[ggg];
t = {1, 2, 3};
s = {2, 5, 6};
Evaluate[ggg @@ t ] = 1;
Evaluate[ggg @@ s] = 2;

Evaluate[ggg @@ t ] = -1;
Evaluate[ggg @@ s] = 3;
```

and the error is

```
Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.
Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 2.
```

A solution may be to use Condition or If, but **does there exist a command to force the new assignment**?

Comment: use `ClearAll[t,s]` before making new assignments?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your code? If ggg is an array, then you can use either Part or ReplacePart, and you probably do not need Evaluate at all.

Comment: `ggg[Sequence @@ t] = -1; ggg[Sequence @@ s] = 3;`.  But I suspect that you'll want to do things a little more naturally, like make `ggg` a `List` rather than assign it `DownValues` as you are doing.

Comment: you get an error because the second time you evaluate `Evaluate[ggg@@t]=-1`, the left hand side of `Set` evaluates to `1` because you have already given it that value with the previous evaluations. `Set` rightly complains that it can't assign a value of `-1` to `1`.

Comment: Is this not the way we should do this **at all**, or is it just me?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer explain your view

Comment: Arrays in Mathematica are usually `List`s, so changing the value of an array element is usually as simple as `arr = {1, 5, 7}; arr[[2]] = 10; arr` gives `{1, 10, 7}`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer yes but in this context i have to change an assignment done previously. Maybe my question is not clear but the answer focuses the point.

Comment: No, both the question and the answer are clear. My point is that this very convoluted way of doing it is not "the way we should do it", like I said above ;) Maybe there is some really good reason for doing it this way, but I can't see it.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer what you have written in the second comment is true but in some cases the indeces of the array/tensor are defined through particular expressions and you can access to the relative element of array /tensor only through `@@`. I think this is the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) to reassign down values:

```
Clear[ggg];
t = {1,2,3};
s = {2,5,6};
Evaluate[ggg @@ t] = 1;
Evaluate[ggg @@ s] = 2;
```

Check initial values:

```
ggg[1,2,3]
ggg[2,5,6]
```

> 1
>
> 2

Reassign using [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive):

```
Activate @ Inactive[Set][Inactive[ggg] @@ t, -1]
Activate @ Inactive[Set][Inactive[ggg] @@ s, 3]
```

> -1
>
> 3

Check:

```
ggg[1,2,3]
ggg[2,5,6]
```

> -1
>
> 3